# UITableview not scrolling smoothly before when every row was appearing?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Now I'm working with uitableview which contains user image set on uibutton, recorded video play on mpmovieplayercontroller like as vine app.

Here my problem is uitableview doesn't scrolling smoothly when goes from one row to another row.

I don't know why this happen. Anybody know the reason give some guidance for how to resolve that kind of issue.

Here I get data from web service.

```
    -(void)feedwebservice
{

    NSString *myurl1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.xyz.com/client/vine-clone/feed/home_feed?user_id=%@&start=%d",AppDelegate.check,navigate];
    NSString  *theurl1=[myurl1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest1=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theurl1]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response; 
    NSError* error12;
    NSData *data1=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest1 returningResponse:&response error:&error12];
    NSString *strResponse1=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableString* responseString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strResponse1];
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dic1 = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];
    for(NSDictionary *subDic in dic1)
    {
        obj=[[DataSet alloc]init];
        obj.data1=[subDic objectForKey:@"channel"];
        obj.data2=[subDic objectForKey:@"followers"];
        obj.data3=[subDic objectForKey:@"following"];
        obj.data4=[subDic objectForKey:@"fullname"];
        obj.data5=[subDic objectForKey:@"post_private"];
        obj.data6=[subDic objectForKey:@"post_sensitive"];
        obj.data7=[subDic objectForKey:@"profile_image"];
        obj.data8=[subDic objectForKey:@"status"];
        obj.data9=[subDic objectForKey:@"title"];
        obj.data10=[subDic objectForKey:@"total_like"];
        obj.data11=[subDic objectForKey:@"total_vine"];
        obj.data12=[subDic objectForKey:@"user_id"];
        obj.data13=[subDic objectForKey:@"user_like"];
        obj.data14=[subDic objectForKey:@"user_vine"];
        obj.data15=[subDic objectForKey:@"video_created_date"];
        obj.data16=[subDic objectForKey:@"video_id"];
        obj.data17=[subDic objectForKey:@"video_name"];
        [feedarr addObject:obj];

}
    //NSLog(@"feedpage count = %u",[feedarr count]);
    [videotable reloadData];
    [pullToRefreshManager_ tableViewReloadFinished];

}
```

Data used on uitableview cell for row at index path

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    /*if(cell == nil)
     {
     }*/

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    obj=[feedarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    profileimgbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [profileimgbtn setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 280, 50, 40)];
    [profileimgbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    [profileimgbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        obj.data7 = [obj.data7 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:obj.data7];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [profileimgbtn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });
    });

    [cell addSubview:profileimgbtn];

    playerview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 250)];
    [playerview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [cell addSubview:playerview];

    obj.data17 = [obj.data17 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj.data17]];
    mc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];

    mc.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    mc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    mc.contentURL = contentURL;
    [mc prepareToPlay];
    mc.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    mc.view.frame = playerview.bounds;
    [mc setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];
    [mc play];
    [playerview addSubview:mc.view];


    //Get the image from the currentPlaybackTime to set it above the player
    thumbnail = [mc thumbnailImageAtTime:[mc currentPlaybackTime] timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mc.view.frame];
    [thumbnailView setImage:thumbnail];
    [thumbnailView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    thumbnailView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [playerview addSubview:thumbnailView];

    singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRollTap:)];
    [singleFingerTap setDelegate:self];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [mc.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    self.moviePlayerController = mc;

    playerActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    playerActivityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(140, 110, 25, 25);
    [playerActivityIndicator startAnimating];
    [playerview addSubview:playerActivityIndicator];
    [self performSelector:@selector(spinnerhide) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `EgoImagebuton` file from the Internet: https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading

Then, use `egoimagebuton` instead of `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thank for your reply. It's working fine. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have commented out cell reuse - which is an amazing performance-saving feature, used to limit the number of cells created and thus the amount the system is taxed.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

obj=[feedarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

...
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I used the above code I got the below error report Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0*50ff2404)

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Surely there is some type of English error message - try scrolling up and down in the console.

Comment: I debug using this line  NSLog(@"debug for cell %@ && %@=",cell,CellIdentifier); I got crash when scrolling from second row to 3 one. In console <UITableViewCell: 0x113562a0; frame = (0 490; 320 490); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x93fa470>> && Cell=

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad, you should not create cell every time:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

/*if(cell == nil)
 {
 }*/

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Should be:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I followed your code, I got the below error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0*50ff2404)

Comment: I debug using this line NSLog(@"debug for cell %@ && %@=",cell,CellIdentifier); I got crash when scrolling from second row to 3 one. In console <UITableViewCell: 0x113562a0; frame = (0 490; 320 490); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x93fa470>> && Cell=

Comment: @raman add exception breakpoint to stop on the line that causes exception — https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I put all subview inside the if(cell==nil) condition. it only display with two results on repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reusing the cell as suggested in other answers, you also need to ensure that in your completion handler the cell that your are assigning the image will be explicitly obtained again by sending the table view a corresponding message which returns the cell based on the *indexPath*.

The reason you need to do this, is that once you reuse cells, and once your completion handler gets executed, the cell isn't associated anymore to the indexPath as it was before.

Thus, in your completion handler re-obtain the cell based on the indexPath:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    MyTableViewCell* cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.addProfileImagegButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
});
```

Here, it is assumed you have subclassed the a `UITableViewCell` which has a property `profileImagegButton`.

Also, if it happens that the cell isn't visible anymore, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns `nil`.

A complete solution however, requires that you implement an image cache, and also prevent  to load a URL when there is currently a request with the same URL pending. You need to check the cache whether it has an image before you set the placeholder image.